# Solved exercises in commutative algebra

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra

I'm looking for books or teaching material with solved exercises in commutative algebra, where can I find them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solutions to ***Atiyah-MacDonald, Introduction to Commutative Algebra*** can be found online (http://dangtuanhiep.files.wordpress.com/2008/09/papaioannoua_solutions_to_atiyah.pdf) and the problems of ***Matsumura's Commutative Ring Theory*** come with hints/solutions at the end.

Comment: Are there online solutions to exercises of Matsumura's Commutative Ring Theory ?

Comment: I am not sure about that, you can search and see what you get.